# GridSplitter утягивается за правую границу окна, несмотря на MinWidth

Tags: wpf, xaml

Хочу сделать окно, разделённое на два столбца вертикальным разделителем так, чтобы столбцы имели ограничение на минимальную ширину, и при изменении размеров окна менялась ширина только правого столбца. Как в Проводнике Windows.
Пишу такой XAML код:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" MinWidth="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300*" MinWidth="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Green"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Background="Yellow"/>

</Grid>
```

Этот код работает не так, как мне надо: почему-то игнорируется MinWidth правого столбца, разделитель беспрепятственно перетаскивается вправо (даже за пределы окна).
Если добавляю звёздочку к значению Width левого столбца (`<ColumnDefinition Width="200*".../>`), MinWidth работает у обоих столбцов, но при изменении размеров окна ширина обоих столбцов меняется пропорционально, а я хочу, чтобы левый сохранял свою ширину.